# DbSet<>.Local ObservableCollection not saving to EF context database

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, prism, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF MVVM application with a DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection returned by DbSet<>.Local. The grid displays content from the database correctly, and changes to the grid change the ObservableCollection, but no changes are saved back to the database.

Context.cs

```
public class AppContext: DbContext 
{
    public AppContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") 
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Field> Fields { get; set; } 
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class EditorViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyEntity> _myEntities;
    private string _message;

    public EditorViewModel()
    {
        var db = new AppContext();
        db.MyEntities.Load();

        this.MyEntities = db.MyEntities.Local;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> MyEntities
    {
        get
        {
            return _myEntities;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_myEntities != value)
            {
                _myEntities = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyEntities");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had thought that changes to the ObservableCollection would automatically write back to the database? Or does SaveChanges need to be called somewhere?

Comment: Sad to let you know but programming doesn't involve magic.  You must track the state(s) of your objects, determine if the user has altered them, determine if the user wishes to save (rather than undo) these changes, then write them back to the database.  Nobody is going to do that for you.

Comment: @Will: "Sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic". It can certainly be tricky to work out what the advanced technology that underpins EF entities can and cannot do when first encountering it. Perhaps this is well illustrated by the fact that it _does_ do some of the things you suggest would need magic to be achieved...

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to this is that using DbSet<>.Local keeps the ObservableCollection in sync with the context, you then just need to call SaveChanges on the context to write back to the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592872.aspx